# What is the use of the prefix "for(;;);" in an Ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook

After using the chrome debugger to inspect the ajax requests of Facebook (for curiosity), I noticed that the response is in JSON, however it is always prefixed with

```
for(;;);
```

In example, if the JSON were `{hello:"world"}`, then Facebook would respond

```
for(;;); {hello:"world"}
```

Does this have any use? I imagine it must have a purpose...

Comment: to force a crash if it is `eval`ed?

Comment: Similar to this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2669690/1102962

Comment: I spent a while looking on google and couldn't find any answers... Thanks for sharing the link

Comment: Oh you got me..

Answer (score 1):

The prevention of [JSON hijacking](https://www.owasp.org/images/6/6a/OWASPLondon20161124_JSON_Hijacking_Gareth_Heyes.pdf) is the use case:

> Evil websites on other domains can't make AJAX requests to get this data due to the same-origin policy, but they can include the URL via a `<script>` tag. The URL is visited with your cookies, and by overriding the global array constructor or accessor methods they can have a method called whenever an object (array or hash) attribute is set, allowing them to read the JSON content.

The empty `for` statement causes an infinite loop, which blocks the data from being used in a non-AJAX context.

**References**

- [OWASP London](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/London)